# How does a red-black tree work?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-tree, red-black-tree

There are lots of questions around about red-black trees but none of them answer how they work.  Why is it called red-black?  How does this keep the tree balanced (thus increasing performance over an unbalanced normal binary search tree)?  I'm just looking for an overview of how and why it works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For searches and traversals, it's the same as any binary tree.

For inserts and deletes, more sophisticated algorithms are applied which aim to ensure that the tree cannot be too unbalanced. These guarantee that all single-item operations will always run in at worst O(log n) time, whereas in a simple binary tree the binary tree can become so unbalanced that it's effectively a linked list, giving O(n) worst case performance for each single-item operation.

The basic idea of the red-black tree is to imitate a B-tree with up to 3 keys and 4 children per node. B-trees (or variations such as B+ trees) are mainly used for database indexes and for data stored on hard disk.

Each binary tree node has a "colour" - red or black. Each black node is, in the B-tree analogy, the subtree root for the subtree that fits within that B-tree node. If this node has red children, they are also considered part of the same B-tree node. So it is possible (though not done in practice) to convert a red-black tree to a B-tree and back, with (most) structure preserved. The only possible anomoly is that when a B-tree node has two keys and three children, you have a choice of which key to goes in the black node in the equivalent red-black tree.

For example, with red-black trees, every line from root to leaf has the same number of black nodes. This rule is derived from the B-tree rule that all leaf nodes are at the same depth.

Although this is the basic idea from which red-black trees are derived, the algorithms used in practice for inserts and deletes are modified to enforce all the B-tree rules (there might be a minor exception - I forget) during updates, but are tailored for the binary tree form. This means that doing a red-black tree insert or delete may give a different structure for the result than that you'd expect comparing with doing the B-tree insert or delete.

For more detail, follow the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree) that MigDus already supplied.

Answer (score 14):

A red-black tree is an ordered binary tree where each vertex is coloured red or black.  **The intuition is that a red vertex should be seen as being at the same height as its parent** (i.e., an edge to a red vertex is thought of as "horizontal" rather than "descending").

[I don't believe the Wikipedia entry makes this point clear.]

The usual rules for red-black trees require that a red vertex never point to another red vertex.  This means that the possible vertex arrangements for any subtree rooted with a black vertex (bbb, bbr, rbb, rbr -- for [left child][root][right child]) correspond to 234 trees.

Searching a red-black tree is just the same as searching an ordinary binary tree.  Insertion and deletion are similar, except that a "fix-up" rotation may be required at some point to preserve the red-black invariant.

Cheers!

Comment: "The intuition is that a red vertex should be seen as being at the same height as its parent (i.e., an edge to a red vertex is thought of as "horizontal" rather than "descending")." *Lightbulb moment, thanks!*